# Remove action defined in class method in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, hook, action

I am trying to remove the action

```
            add_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 30 );
```

it is defined in a method like this

```
    public function yith_quick_view_action_template() {

        // Image.
        add_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_image', 'woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash', 10 );
        add_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_image', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

        // Summary.
        add_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
        add_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
        add_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 15 );
        add_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
        add_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 25 );
        add_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 30 );
    }
```

this method is called in the constructor:

```
    $this->yith_quick_view_action_template();
```

I tried this code but it didn't work
add_action( 'init', function(){
remove_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 30 );
});

I used "plugins_loaded" action as well with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to need to customize yith-quick-view as well, so i tried copying what i did with woocommerce functions.

in functions.php (or in a separate .php file where you want to keep your custom functions) you could add:

```
remove_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 30 );
```

if you want to add it again, you can just type again:

```
add_action( 'yith_wcqv_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 30 );
```

and maybe change the

> 30

in order to reposition its rendering place. a smaller value means higher priority. :)